# multiple inclusion of static library in C

Tags: c, static-libraries

I have `libTimer.a`, `lib2.a`, `lib3.a` and application code.
`lib2.a` created by linking `libTimer.a` (created from `timer.o`) with other object files `a.o` and `b.o`.
Even `lib3.a` also created by linking `libTimer.a` and other object files such as `c.o` and `d.o`.

Now application `main.o` is linked with libraries `lib2.a` and `lib3.a`. 
I understand that size of the application does not increase (multiple inclusion does not happen) by this method. I just tested and found no change in application size when application is built by linking libraries or by adding individual source files `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o`, `d.o` and `timer.o`.

But are there any guidelines in nesting libraries in this way?

Given below is the command summary:

**libTimer.a**

*Compilation Command:*

```
avr-gcc.exe -Os -Wextra -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -std=gnu99 \
    -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DF_CPU=16000000UL \
    -g -Os -Wmain -Wextra -Wall -c CL_Timer.c -o Debug\CL_Timer.o
```

*Linking Command:*

```
avr-g++.exe -o Debug\Timer.elf Debug\Timer.o -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wl,-Map=Debug\timer.map -Wl,--gc-sections
```

*Post Build Command:*

```
avr-ar rcs libTimer.a Debug\timer.o
ranlib libTimer.a
```

**Lib2.a**

*Linking Command:*

```
avr-g++.exe -o Debug\library2.elf Debug\a.o Debug\b.o -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wl,-Map=Debug\library2.map -Wl,--gc-sections .\libTimer.a
```

*Post Build:*

```
avr-ar rcs lib2.a Debug\a.o Debug\b.o
ranlib lib2.a
```

**lib3.a**

*Linking Command:*

```
avr-g++.exe -o Debug\library3.elf Debug\c.o Debug\c.o -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wl,-Map=Debug\library3.map -Wl,--gc-sections .\libTimer.a
```

*Post Build Command:*

```
avr-ar rcs lib3.a Debug\c.o Debug\d.o
ranlib lib3.a
```

**Main Application Linking:**

```
avr-g++.exe -o Debug\main.elf Debug\main.o -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wl,-Map=Debug\main.map -Wl,--gc-sections .\liba.a .\liba.b
```

Comment: How do you have `lib2.a` *contain* `libTimer.a`? Are you sure it *is* contained? Creating a static library with `ar`, you just add all its `.o` files to one archive file. You typically don't care about dependencies but leave them to the final linking step of an executable using the library (eg. when linking `lib2.a`, you **must** also link `libTimer.a` after it).

Comment: A static library doesn't "contain" any other libraries, a static library is nothing more than an archive of object files.

Comment: rephrased original post for clarity. May be my words "contain" is wrong. It is only linking with libraries.

Comment: rephrasing doesn't help. `.a` libraries are not created by linking. Perhaps what you need is show the actual commands how you create these?

Comment: I think what you mean is "depends upon". If two libraries both depend on a third, that's OK as long as they don't require different versions.

Comment: Did you consider having *shared libraries* ?

Comment: I think I got confused how library is created. I updated the post again with summary of commands. I realized that libTimer.a is only used for linking, but it will not be there in either liba.a or lib3.a. I was of the opinion that linking along with library will add code of the library file also and that is why this confussion came. Let me try again in different way and cross verify this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show as "*linking commands*" is unnecessary except for your main application. I'm actually surprised that it doesn't throw errors, as your library code shouldn't contain `main()`.

The commands creating the *static library* are the `ar` commands (in your case the cross-compiler `avr-ar` commands). The only thing they do is to place all object files for the library in an archive file (`*.a`).

With *shared libraries*, you would have some dependency information, so a *shared library* can link against another *shared library*. With *static libraries*, no such thing exists, they are just archives of object files and in your final linking step of your main application, you have to make sure to link all required libraries. Therefore, with `liba` and `libb` both depending on `libTimer` as you describe, the final linking step is wrong, it should look like this:

```
avr-g++.exe -o Debug\main.elf Debug\main.o -mmcu=atmega328p \
    -Wl,-Map=Debug\main.map -Wl,--gc-sections .\liba.a .\libb.a .\libTimer.a
```

This assumes they are actually named `liba.a` and `libb.a` -- you have some confusion in your question with libraries called `lib2.a` and `lib3.a` as well.

**Important thing to note**: In your linking command, always list libraries and object files *before their dependencies*. The linker works by maintaining *unresolved symbols* and can only resove them from libraries and object files coming later at the command line.